# Minimum Knowledge required in Datastructres

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I have found numerous data-structures on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures), also have also looked into several books in data-structures and found that they vary. I want to know what are the basic or minimum list of data-structure knowledge a new CS graduate should have?

Also is it necessary to know their implementation in more than one programming knowledge considering there is a difference in the implementation. If i know the implementation of Linked list in C should i know its Java based implementation?

It would be great if you could help me understand categorically:

- Basic datastructures(necessary for a CS grad)
- Advanced Datastructures

Edit : i am more interested in the list of data structures.

Comment: this does not seem like a real question.. you want to know generally about data structures? take the data structures course.

Comment: This question might have been suited for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Comment: @Raphael please let me know how i can transfer this to the right forum like you suggested.

Comment: @WeaselFox i am more interested in the **list** rather than about the data-structures for which a course is a default source.

Comment: @mak89k It is not yet live. Please follow the link I posted above for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really a little too broad, even the way you've narrowed it down, because it depends on what sort of future path you're looking at.  Grad school?  PhD track?  Industry?  Which industry?

But as a rough minimum, I'd say, take a look at CLRS (as Raphael suggests) and pick out the following:

- Linked lists, and the variations like stacks, queues, etc.
- Basic heaps
- Basic hash tables
- Trees, especially including binary search trees, and preferably familiarity with at least one self-balancing BST
- Graphs, both matrix-representation and adjacency list representation

And probably some more based on what sort of job you're looking for.  As someone on a PhD track... well.  All of them.  At some point you will take a qualifier and be expected to know most of them.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11866) by Cormen et al. In my experience, if you know what is in there you are set for anything coming at you.

I would not consider knowing any implementation very useful. If you know the basics you should be able to implement your own version quickly, but chances are you will never have to because there are libraries for that. So the rule for practice is: know your libraries!

Even so, it is important that you know properties of data structures (e.g. space overhead, runtimes of central operations, behaviour under concurrent accesses, (im)mutability, ...) so you will always use the one best suited to your task at hand.

Comment: Agreed.  Though it's worth knowing the complexity of the operations against each of the data structures.  How long does it take to insert in to a linked list, or a hashmap, how long does it take to delete from an array, etc.  It's important to know the best data structure -- google will remember the implementation details for you ;)

Comment: Runtimes were definitely intended when I wrote "properties". Editing for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MIT's OCW [Intro to Algorithm Course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/) It is great tutorial theoretically.
For practicing data structures in Java check : Data Structures & Algorithms in Java by Robert Lafore, it is excellent.
Implementation in one language is sufficient, but try to solve it in structured-oriented language like C and OO language like Java/ C++. This will help a lot while preparing for interviews.
One good resource for basic data structures in C : [here](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/)